# How to call the right constructor of a template type?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, initialization

In the following code, how can I make the commented line working in the same way as the line just above of it?

I would like to make it a generic code, that call suitable constructor of a template `Type`.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Type>
struct Class
{
    Type data;
    Class(Type data) : data(data) { }
};

int main()
{
    Class<std::string> a = std::string("abc");
    // Class<std::string> b = "abc";
    std::cout << a.data << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use direct initialization:

```
Class<std::string> b("abc");
```

Answer (score 17):

Use [braced-init-list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)(or uniform-initiation) to initlize the instance of `Class`.

```
Class<std::string> a{ std::string("abc") };  // works
Class<std::string> b{ "abc" };               // also works
```

Answer (score 14):

```
Class<std::string> b = "abc";
```

is [copy-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). It doesn't work because it would involve two user-defined conversions:

- from `const char*` to `std::string`,
- from `std::string` to `Class<std::string>`.

But at most one is allowed.

When you write

```
Class<std::string> b("abc");
// or
Class<std::string> b{"abc"};
```

you use [direct-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization). It works because now only one user-defined conversion is used:

- from `const char*` to `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to change your `Class`, you could add a templated converting constructor. Then you'd be able to compile the commented line as written in your example. Notehowever, that it is generally not recommended to use implicit conversions without decent reason as they may result in hard-to-spot bugs (cf the [C++ Core Guidlines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ro-conversion)).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Type>
struct Class
{
    Type data;
    Class(Type data) : data(data) { }

    template<typename Other>
    Class(Other other_data) : data(other_data) {}
};


int main()
{
    Class<std::string> a = std::string("abc");
    Class<std::string> b = "abc";
    Class<std::string> c = a;

    std::cout << b.data << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you can use C++14, you could use the `std::literals::string_literals::operator""s` and remove the converting constructor. Then, your line would look like this:

```
using namespace std::literals;

Class<std::string> b = "abc"s;
```

Live code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/y5Zc2R).